# Google Chrome Remote Desktop does not work for Ubuntu from windows

Tags: desktop, remote

Accessing Ubuntu fron windows does not work

Is it because of proxy settings?

I used https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/ to setup remote devices, Ubuntu device does not get set up.

What should I do now?

it stays in "please try again in a minute" forever.

[screenshot - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS6pv.jpg)

unable to reach remote computer

[screenshot - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK1sb.jpg)

Comment: We'll need more information to help... What did happen? Did you install the extension? Is there an error message?

Comment: I followed the steps as in https://remotedesktop.google.com/access